# "SELECT DISTINCT" ignores different cases

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the problem, that MSSQL Server 2000 should select some distinct values from a table (the specific column is of the nvarchar type).
There are the sometimes the same values, but with different cases, for example (pseudocode):

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM ("A", "a", "b", "B")
```

would return

```
A,b
```

But I do want (and do expect)

```
A,a,b,B
```

because they actually are different values.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: What collation do you use for the column?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The collation will be set to case insensitive.

You need to do something like this

```
Select distinct col1 COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as
From dbo.myTable
```

Comment: I didn't know COLLATE, but that is the solution.
I'll accept this one, as soon as I am allowed to (6 minutes left).
Thank you!

Comment: Dont forget to add 'as col1' in order to avoid loosing column name in result!

Comment: `latin1_general_ci` works for most Latin characters, but `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, as shown by [`show collation`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-collation.html) should work for everything.

Comment: I had to remove my GROUP BY clause to have it work.

Comment: @AdamHuffman you should use `COLLATE` in your `GROUP BY` clause as well

Comment: @CeesTimmerman anything _ci means case insensitive. we are trying to use case sensitive collation to differentiate "A" from "a". 

These are the suffixes for collation names: 

`_ai` = Accent-insensitive; 
`_as` = Accent-sensitive; 
`_ci` = Case-insensitive; 
`_cs` = Case-sensitive;
`_bin` = Binary

Answer (score 11):

Not sure about MS SQL but with MySQL or postgres, use `BINARY` for this operation. Cast the column to binary like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT BINARY(column1) from table1;
```

Just change `column1` and `table1` as per your schema.

Full example that works for me in MySQL 5.7, should work for others:

```
SELECT DISTINCT BINARY(gateway) from transactions;
```

Cheers!

Comment: Much cleaner option!

Comment: This is so much better. I don't want to change the collation of every table in which I have to do a search like this.

Comment: NOTE: This is for MySQL, not Microsoft SQL which was asked.

Comment: I was really hoping this would work on Postgres but no luck

Comment: does it work for you in postgres without the cast to binary? Try `SELECT DISTINCT column1 from table1`. Or if you need to cast something like this maybe `SELECT DISTINCT name::text from clients;`

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   CasedTheColumn 
FROM
   (
   SELECT TheColumn COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_BIN AS CasedTheColumn
   FROM myTAble
   )FOO
WHERE
   CasedTheColumn IN ('A', 'a'...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the [collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-charsets.html) of the column in question to something binary, e.g. [utf8-bin](http://www.webmasterworld.com/databases_sql_mysql/3425464.htm). You can either do that [in the `SELECT` statement itself](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-collate.html) or by changing your table structure directly (which means it doesn't have to map the collation each time the query is run, since it will store it correctly internally).

Answer (score -1):

SELECT * FROM students
WHERE BINARY(name) = BINARY('alex');

Comment: Please explain how your code works and why it solves the problem. Try for [answer].