# MySQL case-insensitive DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, sql, database, distinct, case-insensitive

Can anyone tell me how i can SELECT DISTINCT from my database without it being case-sensitive?

My query is

```
SELECT DISTINCT email FROM `jm_order`
```

The results brings out all the emails in the table but repeats the ones with different cases. This is expected because the values are different case wise.
e.g

```
sam@gmail.com
josh@gmail.com
Sam@gmail.com
john@gmail.com
```

But what i want is for the same emails, to be grouped together regardless of the case. What adjustment can i make to my SQL to stop it from repeating for example `sam@gmail.com` and `Sam@gmail.com` just because they are different cases?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["SELECT DISTINCT" ignores different cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644851/select-distinct-ignores-different-cases)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try to use `upper` function

```
SELECT DISTINCT UPPER(email) FROM `jm_order`
```

you can also use `lower` instead

```
SELECT DISTINCT LOWER(email) FROM `jm_order`
```

[**More information**](http://www.sqlinfo.net/mysql/mysql_function_upper_lower.php).

Answer (score 9):

If you want to preserve the case of the email (so it actually matches one of the rows), you can do:

```
select email
from jm_order
group by lower(email);
```

Comment: Does this really work? How it this even possible? How would the DBMS know which result it should return.

Comment: @T3rm1 . . . MySQL returns an email from an arbitrary matching row.  In more recent versions of MySQL, this would actually generate an error using the default settings.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LOWER(email) AS email 
FROM `jm_order`
```