# MySQL SELECT DISTINCT should be case sensitive?

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct, case-sensitive

How do I make MySQL's SELECT DISTINCT case sensitive?

```
create temporary table X (name varchar(50) NULL);
insert into X values ('this'), ('This');
```

Now this query:

```
select distinct(name) from X;
```

Results in:

> this

What's going on here?  I'd like SELECT DISTINCT to be case sensitive.  Shouldn't that be the default?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["SELECT DISTINCT" ignores different cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644851/select-distinct-ignores-different-cases)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use [`BINARY` operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-binary-op.html) for that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(BINARY name) AS Name FROM X;
```

You can also [`CAST`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) it while selecting:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
(CAST(name AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8) COLLATE utf8_bin) AS Name FROM X;
```

#### See this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/590497/1)

Comment: This is nice and simple, but it turns out BINARY messes up non-ASCII characters.  If, for example, instead of ('this', 'This') we use (entrée, Entrée'), then SELECT DISTINCT(BINARY(...)) returns blobs.  Instead, you can use COLLATE as @roberto-navarro suggested (except not in the CREATE statement) as follows: `SELECT DISTINCT NAME COLLATE latin1_bin FROM X;`

Comment: Learn something new everyday... Had no idea that this was occurring... Life is complete now

Comment: @ishmael I think this should be its own answer, it was the quickest and simplest approach for me!

Answer (score 9):

I would rather update the column definition to be case sensitive collision.

Like this:

```
create table X (name VARCHAR(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NULL);
insert into X values ('this'), ('This');
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/add276/2/0

Answer (score 2):

You can use a hashing function (MD5) and then group on that.

```
SELECT Distinct(MD5(Cat)), Cat FROM (
  SELECT 'Cat'
    UNION ALL
  SELECT 'cat'
) AS BOW
```

SQL Output:

[image]