# MySQL SELECT DISTINCT is case insensitive?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, r

I am trying to cleanup some data that I imported into  MySQL from a pandas dataframe.

some appears as:

```
VARIABLE
```

others as:

```
Variable
```

when I use

```
SELECT DISTINCT
```

it seems that MySQL treats Variable as equivilent to VARIABLE.

When I import this into R though R sees Variable and VARIABLE as different.
And running

```
as.factor
```

gives me two factors.
How can I make MySQL's SELECT DISTINCT case sensitive so that I can detect and fix the data for import into R to analyse?

Comment: You are probably using a case insensitive collation.  You want a case sensitive one.  Read about it here:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-collate.html.

Comment: [Use `BINARY` as seen in this SO post.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19462919/mysql-select-distinct-should-be-case-sensitive)

Comment: I set everything to UTF-8 earlier in the pandas code so BINARY blobs everything. I think I'll look into switching the MySQL COLLATION to default to something case sensitive. any pointers on the command line?

Comment: When I bring data into R from SQL, I almost always do `stringsAsFactors = F`, apply `tolower()` to all the strings, and then covert the ones I want as factors to factors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["SELECT DISTINCT" ignores different cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644851/select-distinct-ignores-different-cases)

Answer (score 2):

You could just use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT BINARY Name
FROM tablename
```

the [BINARY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-binary-op.html) operator will cast a string to a BINARY string, and comparison between binary strings will be case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna detect the lower and upper cases which are in your table use this

```
   SELECT name                        //this to select lower names
   FROM yourtable 
   where name = BINARY LOWER(Name)

   union all

   SELECT name                      //this to select upper names
   FROM yourtable 
   where name = BINARY UPPER(Name)

   union all                       // this to select not lower and not upper

   SELECT name 
   FROM yourtable 
   where name != BINARY UPPER(Name)
   and   name != BINARY LOWER(Name)
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f9db/12)