# Generate ID for duplicate values in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I found following link to assign identical ID to duplicates in SQL server, 
my understanding there is no sql server function to automatically generate it rather than using insert and update queries in link attached, is that statement True, if yes, then what would be the trigger if for example someone insert data to MyTable then run insert and update query from link:

[Assign identical ID to duplicates in SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35148867/assign-identical-id-to-duplicates-in-sql-server)

```
 INSERT INTO secondTable (word) SELECT distinct word FROM MyTable;
 UPDATE MyTable SET ID = (SELECT id from secondTable where MyTable.word = secondTable.word)
```

thanks,
S

Comment: Have you googled how to create a insert/update trigger?

Comment: Yes, I google it but didn't find anything or couldn't understand how to apply my case.

Comment: Do you need the id column?

Comment: Trigger will execute code on insert/update that will search the table for the value from the inserted/updated values and modify the original data and your new values. Triggers are not special (well, just a little), you can do anything you want inside a trigger. What is special about triggers, is access to inserted/updated data, so you know what data is being inserted/modified.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? I can't think of an "automatic" solution that would just increase the Id for new words.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    Id INT NOT NULL,
    Word NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (Id, Word)); -- primary key will make it impossible to have more than one combination of word and id

DECLARE @word NVARCHAR(255) = 'Hello!';

-- Get existing id or calculate a new id 
DECLARE @Id INT = (SELECT Id FROM MyTable WHERE Word = @word);
IF(@id IS NULL) SET @Id = (SELECT MAX(Id) + 1 FROM MyTable);

INSERT INTO MyTable (Id, Word)
VALUES (@id, @word)

SELECT * FROM MyTable
```

If you can't for some reason have id and word as a combined primary key, you may use an unique index to make sure that there is only one combination