# Unique values wihtout losing the source of duplicates mysql

Tags: mysql, distinct-values

I have a table with DNA sequence data that looks like this:

```
id   organism_name       dna_sequence
1    homo sapiens        AAAA
2    mus musculus        TTCT
3    cannabis sativa     AAGC
4    physalis peruviana  AAAA
5    quercus humboldti   GCGC
```

For the purposes of my work, I must work with the distinct sequences, otherwise, there will be redundancy. However, if I use the `SELECT DISTINCT` approach I will lose the origin of the organisms that have the AAAA sequence. I think that a solution could be to sort the sequences by alphabetic order and add a new id that representes the equal sequences, but i don't now how to do it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I can offer two options here.  First, if you are using MySQL 8+, then `ROW_NUMBER()` can be used to assign a unique sequence to all organisms sharing the same DNA sequence:

```
SELECT
    id,
    organism_name,
    dna_sequence,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dna_sequence ORDER BY organism_name) seq
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY id;
```

Another option would be to just report a single row for each DNA sequence, but then aggregate all organisms together using `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT
    dna_sequence,
    GROUP_CONCAT(organism_name ORDER BY organism_name) organisms
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    dna_sequence
ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: Hi Tim, I used the second approach because I have MySQL 5, I got two columns, sequence and organisms. Seems that the output will be the same sequence duplicated in several rows and the organism next, but this still doesn't separate the different sequences, in my original table, which is giant, I don't know where a different sequence start and where ends

Comment: Please add your expected output to the question.

Comment: Hi Tim and everyone interested in the solution, this post has the answer to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35148867/assign-identical-id-to-duplicates-in-sql-server